# Convert a directory of csv files into a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, finance, python-datetime, yahoo-finance

I used yahoo finance to download the Russelll 2000 index with the following columns:

```
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Dividends',
       'Stock Splits', 'SMA_50', 'SMA_100', 'SMA_150', 'SMA_200']
```

However, my issue is that I can't convert the 'date' column into a datetime object.

I made the following function:

```py
def make_datetime(dir_path):
    # Get a list of all CSV files in the directory
    csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

    # Loop through each CSV file
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        # Read in the CSV file
        csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path, csv_file)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

        # Convert the 'Date' column to pandas datetime object
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', utc=True)

        # Save the modified DataFrame back to the CSV file
        df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)

make_datetime('my_directory')
```

I have tried to put a `print .dtypes after df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)` and it prints that it is now a datetime object but when I pick a single stock and uses .dtypes it says it is an object.

I have tried the following which works:

```py
ARGO_file = pd.read_csv('ARGO.csv')
ARGO_file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ARGO_file['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', utc=True)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do in `make_datetime`? It seems you just convert csv to df to csv; csv is just text so I don't see where exactly you're missing a datetime data type.